# Anaconda Prompt Closing after Keras installation

Tags: windows, command-line, python, anaconda

So I recently downloaded Keras through the Anaconda prompt (I've downloaded other packages successfully). It actually worked, as I was able to import Keras in Jupyter Notebook. However, now I get the following issue when I open the Anaconda prompt:

```
C:\Users\[User Name]>python C:\Users\[User Name]\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt
    python: can't open file 'C:\Users

\[User]': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\[User Name]>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\Users\[User Name]>del temp.txt

C:\Users\[User Name]>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
```

Things to Note:

At first, I simply cannot type or enter anything into the window.
After closing and reopening it, the same message opens up, but is followed by a bunch of text I can't read because the window immediately closes afterward.
In the error message provided, the third line has [User] instead of user. That is because my user's folder name on my computer is "FirstName LastName". There is a space which I'm wondering might be the issue.
I don't want to uninstall Anaconda, as I have a project due in a few days and don't want any installation/loss of data issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the space in your user name is the issue. 
If your user name is `Jay kishan Panjiyar`, type

```
python "C:\Users\Jay kishan Panjiyar\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py"  > temp.txt
```

at the prompt, using quotes to tell the system that
that string with spaces in it is all one filename. 
Or, if you're in your home directory (`C:\Users\Jay kishan Panjiyar`)
when you do this (as your illustration suggests),
it should be good enough to say

```
python Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  > temp.txt
```

P.S. Plain `>` is equivalent to `1>`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is faced by many Python developers. Don't worry and try to resolve it by following below guidelines -

1.Uninstall Keras first (you can delete keras files by going inside folder where package is installed)

2.goto the location C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\etc\conda\activate.d

You can see the keras batch files inside in both activate.d and deactivate.d, which runs every time the anaconda prompt is opened.DELETE them.

3.Reinstall Keras.